# ¿Por que no entra a la base de datos?

Tags: c#, .net-core

estoy haciendo una pequeña api en .NetCore6 con la librería dapper y Mysql, el caso es que cuando hago una consulta, me sale el siguiente error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Es una base de datos de mysql en aws. Por ahora lo estoy probando con postman.

Este es el codigo:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(Entities.product product)
    {
        IEnumerable<Entities.product> result;
        using(var db = new MySqlConnection(connectionDB))
        {
            var query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url_image, p.price, p.discount, p.category FROM product AS p Where p.category = @idCategory";
            result = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, product.id);
        }
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Le estoy mandando el parámetro desde postman con un json, asi:

```
{
"id": 1
}
```

Comment: El error lo tira dapper o al hacer la conexion?

Comment: Es cuando sale de esta linea: result = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, product.id);
Pienso que a lo mejor le estoy mandando mal el dato de product.id, porque tengo otra donde solo me traae la información sin ponerle parametro y no me da ese error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Armando la query de manera dinámica
var query = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Id=@Id";
var paramName = "@Id"; // también funciona sin la @
var paramValue = 3;

//Dynamic parameters agregados individualmente
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) // Mismo efecto si le das al MySQL
{
    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParameters.Add(paramName, paramValue);

    var results = con.Query<Movie>(query, dynamicParameters);
    return results;
}
```

Referencia: https://makolyte.com/csharp-adding-dynamic-query-parameters-with-dapper/

Comment: porque complicarla tanto.. te voy a mostrar otro metodo..

Comment: ¡Siempre aportas cosas de leyenda, sos un capo!

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la respuesta anterior es correcta, todo el codigo se puede simplificar usando una clase anonima.

```
result = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, 
    new 
    {
        idCategory = product.id
    });
```

Tambien, podrias simplificar la clase anonima si cambiar el nombre del parametro en el query:

```
var query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url_image, p.price, p.discount, p.category FROM product AS p Where p.category = @id";
result = db.Query<Entities.product>(query, 
    new 
    {
        product.id
    });
```

Como la variable dentro del query se llama igual que la variable a pasar, entoncees Dapper la infiere desde ahi.